# Second function has forgotten the selected value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get data from the database using a ajax function. But some parts of the code are not working. The $car_id, witch is the selected value in the dropdown is forgotten in the second part of the function.

First of all. I have a dropdown where the user can select a car:

```
<select name="car_id" id="car_id" onChange="getCar(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Volvo XC90</option>
    <option value="2">Saab 95</option>
    <option value="3">Mercedes SLK</option>
    <option value="4">Audi TT</option>
</select>
```

After selecting (onChange event) my script runs the following function:

```
<script> 
function getCar(selectedItem) {
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: 'get1.php', 
        method: 'POST', 
        data: {'car_id' : jQuery('#car_id').val()},
        success: function(response){ 
            jQuery('#car_id').val(response); 
            jQuery('#car_brand').val(response);
            getCar2()
            }, 
        error: function (request, status, error) { 
            alert(request.responseText); 
            }, 
        }); 
    } 
</script>
```

This function runs the following SQL query:
`SELECT car_brand FROM cars WHERE car_id = $car_id`

The function gets the `car_brand` from the database and posts it into the `#car_brand` textfield. This part of the code works fine. But as you can see, the function calls a second function:

```
<script> 
function getCar2(selectedItem) {
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: 'get2.php', 
        method: 'POST', 
        data: {'car_id' : jQuery('#car_id').val()},
        success: function(response){ 
            jQuery('#car_id').val(response); 
            jQuery('#car_model').val(response);
            }, 
        error: function (request, status, error) { 
            alert(request.responseText); 
            }, 
        }); 
    } 
</script>
```

This time the function tries to get the `car_model`. The function needs to post this into the `#car_model` textfield. But this is not working. When I look to the firebug console I see that second function `getCar2` has forgot the $car_id.

When I select value 3 the first function runs the SQL statement:
`SELECT car_brand FROM cars WHERE car_id = 3`
and the second function:
`SELECT car_model FROM cars WHERE car_id =`

How can I solve this problem?

**Update 1:**

```
<?php    

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) ;
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error) ;
}else {
    $car_id = isset($_POST['car_id'])?$_POST['car_id']:'';
    $car_brand = isset($_POST['car_brand'])?$_POST['car_brand']:'';

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car_id="' . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $car_id) . '"';    
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) ;
  if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
     $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
    echo $result['car_brand'];   
  }else{
     $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ;
    echo "";  
  }    
} 

?>
```

Comment: nowhere do we see `<select name="car_id" id="car_id" onChange="getCar2(this.value)">` - Notice the added `2`?

Comment: I have no problem with this part of the code

Comment: you posted `<select name="car_id" id="car_id" onChange="getCar(this.value)">` but haven't shown us where you're doing `<select name="car_id" id="car_id" onChange="getCar2(this.value)">`, which I don't get, *sorry*. If it's not a console issue, check for errors with error reporting and against your query.

Comment: Aha, now I see the "2". No, there is no onChange event for `getCar2`. The `getCar` function starts the `getCar2` function

Comment: your not passing any value into the get second method from your first function call

Comment: Ah ok, I get it now. Well, TBH; jQuery isn't my strongest points (*as you can tell*), but it might have something to do with your MySQL query and how it's being called/processed which you didn't post. Hard to say really. If it's JS related, then wait for someone who's better at it than I. ;-)

Comment: The only thing I can think is to verify the `response` being assigned by `jQuery('#car_id').val(response);` in the `getCar` function to ensure it's actually assigning a valid value (which ends up being the value used in `getCar2`).

Comment: @Fred-ii- see Update 1 in my first post for the PHP/SQL query. This is the code for `get1.php`. The other script `get2.php` is the same. The only difference is that `get2.php` is posting the result for `car_model`.

Comment: @CaffeineFueled do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: So, it looks to me like you're assigning the `car_brand` to the `<select>` element which is an invalid value.  The `<select>` is looking for a numeric value between 0 and 4 which is why you're getting an empty value in `getCar2`.  I'm pretty sure if you remove `jQuery('#car_id').val(response);` from both functions you'll have better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `jQuery('#car_id').val(response);` from getCar. no need to update it as its allready have car_id

```
<script> 
    function getCar(selectedItem) {
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            url: 'get1.php', 
            method: 'POST', 
            data: {'car_id' : jQuery('#car_id').val()},
            success: function(response){ 

                jQuery('#car_brand').val(response);
                getCar2()
                }, 
            error: function (request, status, error) { 
                alert(request.responseText); 
                }, 
            }); 
        } 
    </script>
```

Comment: Do I need to remove this from `getCar` or from `getCar2`?

Comment: remove from both function

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are reassigning `#car_id` to a new value in the function `getCar()`, with this line: `jQuery('#car_id').val(response);`.

You are assigning two dom elements the same value `response` in the first functions ajax callback. I don't know if that is what you are intending to do or not. You are passing the `getCar()` function the actual value of the `select` element via the `selectedItem` variable. If you indeed, need to reassign the value of `#car_id`, you should pass the `selectedItem` variable on to the `getCar2` function, which should still contain, the originally selected value, and use that in the `getCar2` function.

Otherwise, remove the line `jQuery('#car_id').val(response);` from the `getCar` function, and you could also remove the passing of the variable to the two functions, as you are not using them anywhere else.